# Describe geometrically all linear combinations of $u = [1,0,0] \quad v = [0,1,1] \quad w = [1,1,1] $

Tags: linear-algebra

> Describe geometrically (as a line, plane, etc.) all linear combinations of 
>   $$ 
>   u = [1,0,0] \quad v = [0,1,1] \quad w = [1,1,1]
> $$

I understand that $w$ is a linear combination of $u$ and $v$ such that $u + v = w$, though I believe that my problem is in understanding the actual question.

Comment: The span of two linearly independent vectors is a plane. The span of one non-zero vector is a line. In this case, we have a plane.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the question means. You have 3 vectors:
$$
\vec{u} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, 
\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, 
\vec{w} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
If I pick any 3 real numbers $a,b,c$ and consider a vector $a\vec{u} + b \vec{v} + c\vec{w}$, I get another vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If I look at all possible vectors of this form, for any values of $a,b,c$, what do I get - a line, a plane, etc.

**HINT** Note that $\vec{u} + \vec{v} = \vec{w}$ and $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: sorry typo fixed it u = [1,0,0]

Comment: @whattheheckV fixed and added hint for you, can you do this problem now?

Answer (score 1):

Actually $w=u+v$, hence the subspace generated by $u,v,w$ is the same as the subspace generated by $u$ and $v$. As these are linearly independent (for obvious reasons), they generate a subspace of dimension $2$, i.e. a plane.

Comment: Seems that using Gaussian elimination have made $w=u$, but this way could have made $w=v$ too; i.e. after operation $w\leftarrow w-v$.

Comment: @jiten: Actually, it was only a typo in my answer, that I've fixed. Thanks for drawing my attention on this!

Comment: Thanks for vindication. Request your answer to another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1364997/424260.