How to Geometrically Interpret the Solutions of a $3\times3$ Linear System
I'm currently going over the geometric interpretations of $3\times3$ linear solutions, and the different combinations that these planes can arrange themselves. Three planes in space can have any of the following eight arrangments:

All coincident. (No issues)
Two coincident and one intersecting.
Two coincident and one parallel.
Two parallel and one intersecting.
All three parallel. (No issues)
All meet at one point. (No issues)
All meet in a common line. (No issues)
The line of intersection of any two is parallel to the third plane.

When converting a $3\times3$ system into an augmented matrix and applying row operations to achieve echelon form:
\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b & c & \vdots & d \\
  0 & e & f & \vdots & g\\
  0 & 0 & h & \vdots & i
\end{bmatrix}
I want to know how to determine each of the aforementioned arrangements based off the echelon form of the system, (whilst also allowing tests regarding the normal of each plane).
Trivially, I know that if $h\ne0$, $z$ will have a unique solution, and all planes will have meet at one point (6).
Additionally, if $h=0$ and $i=0$ then $z$ is a free parameter $t$ and the planes will meet at a common line with parameter $t$ (7).
The situation where all planes are coincident and parallel are fairly trivial as well, (1 & 5).
I am confused on the remaining 4 and any help is appreciated.

Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364997/understanding-geometry-of-linear-system?rq=1 ?

It does not unfortunately, I'm more interested in the roles of the elements of the echelon representation.

What planes are you referring to? The three planes defined by the original three equations? If so, then you should keep in mind that the original three equations are discarded as the original augmented matrix is converted into echelon form. It is possible for different configurations of the original three planes to produce the same echelon form.

You can't distinguish these cases by the echelon form alone:
For example if you have $h=0$ and $i \ne 0$, the linear $3 \times 3$ system does note have a solution. This could be case 3 (two coincident and one parallel) or 4 (two parallel and one intersecting) or 5 (all three parallel) or 8 (The line of intersection of any two is parallel to the third plane).
On the level of solving the set of linear equations, they are all equal in that there is not a single point on all three of the planes. To get more info on which case we are in, you would have to compare normal directions of the planes to check if (and how many) of them are parallel to each other.
If we have $h \ne 0$, then the value of $z$ is determined, but then depending on whether $e =0$ or $e \ne 0$ (and later on the same for $a$) there might still be situations where the system does not have a solution, which means we are once again in the cases 3,4,5 or 8.
If $a,e, h \ne 0$, then the system is uniquely solvable which is case 6.
If we can choose one variable freely (which is the case if $h=i=0$), we are in case 2 or 7 which again, we can't distinguish by just looking at the set of equations alone.
If we can choose two variable freely we are in case 1.
